# Getting SQLPlus to spool out Unicode characters, are being output as?

Tags: oracle, utf-8, oracle10g, sqlplus

I am attempting to get Oracle sqlplus (10.2) to spool out Unicode data on a Linux machine. I have found several discussions of this issue, but no clear answers, other than to check locale settings and set NLS_LANG to AL32UTF8. All locale info is set to "en_US.UTF-8", I'll post the full output upon request.

The OS (vi, etc.), will recognize and accept Unicode characters without issue. However, when using sqlplus, all non-ASCII characters are changed to ? characters. The Oracle DB has NLS_CHARACTERSET set to AL32UTF8, and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET set to AL16UTF16.

Am I missing some setting or switch that needs to be set for sqlplus itself? Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer to this. Apparently, setting NLS_LANG (the correct setting is AMERICAS_AMERICA.AL32UTF8) in the shell script does not work. It must be exported:

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
```

Comment: Supposed to be:
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

Comment: Thanks! Fixed accordingly.

Comment: I was plagued by this issue for days. It worked great on Windows in both command prompt and cygwin shells scrips... but not on linux itself. After doing export it all worked :). For me it also workd in the non-language specific version: export NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8

Comment: As a footnote, changing NLS_LANG to support UTF8 may cause SQL*Plus to output columns as different widths if they're defined in CHAR length semantics instead of BYTE.  If you need to ensure a column's formatting, you *must* manually `COLUMN x FORMAT y`.