# Oracle to export data with chinese character

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have oracle database that I can use to store/display chinese characters.
But when I am using sqlplus to query the database (e.g. running script from sqlplus) the chinese character can't be displayed (all question marks). My purpose is eventually to export the data to CSV files (that contains chinese characters). Any comment on how I can do it?

Comment: You can try with SQL Developer. It  has that facility. You just need to execute your SQL and export the output as CSV.

Comment: If you're on a Linux machine, the please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179181/getting-sqlplus-to-spool-out-unicode-characters-are-being-output-as.

Comment: What is the database character set?  What is the client `NLS_LANG` setting?  What is the client code page?  What is actually stored in the database when you use the `dump(column_name)` function?

Comment: The link from Codo really works. Thanks! also to everyone who responded. Cheers!